# Why isn't my program drawing anything?

Tags: javascript, processing

I made this program that will hopefully draw a cool shape based on the sliders. The problem is, nothing is showing up other than the sliders! Why is this?

```js
var aslider, lslider, sslider, newx, newy;
function setup() {
  createCanvas(300,300);
  aslider = createSlider(1,359,17);
  lslider = createSlider(1,50,10);
  sslider = createSlider(1,50,20);
}

function draw() {
  var angle = aslider.value();
  var length = lslider.value();
  var size = sslider.value();
  var startx = width / 2;
  var starty = height / 2;
  var radians = angle * (Math.PI/180);
  for (var i = 0; i++; i < size) {
    newx = startx * Math.sin(radians) + starty * Math.cos(radians);
    newy = startx * Math.sin(radians) + starty * -Math.cos(radians);
    line(startx, starty, newx, newy);
    startx = newx;
    starty = newy;
  }
}
```

Comment: set up a demo on something like jsfiddle please...

Comment: How do you call the draw funciton?

Comment: Better than using a jsfiddle (the link to which might break one day), use the code snippet tool provided by StackOverflow. Especially, we need to know what your `createCanvas()` and `createSlider()` functions do, in order to be able to reproduce your example.

Comment: In your snippet, you never call either of your functions. Is this just for sake of brevity?

Comment: Hello everybody, I forgot to mention that I am using processing!

Comment: Hes using the p5.js library which calls setup() and draw() automatically

Comment: @lol at what line is the error showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your for loop is wrong. It should be

```
for (var i = 0; i < size; i++)
```

I tested it here: http://codepen.io/eerk/pen/wgOZVW?editors=1010